# Batch - concatenate a string with file names in a folder to pass to a CLI program

Tags: batch-file

i'm having a bad time trying to write a script that takes a list of files from a given folder (the folder itself inside a folder containing several identical folders like these) and "queue" the final filename string to be read by a program (the program in question is [icobundle](http://telegraphics.com.au/sw/product/ICOBundle), which takes a list of files and "concatenates" all in a .ico), like this:

```
icobundle -o output.ico file1.png file2.png file3.png ...
```

The folder structure is as follows:

```
.\
|-- first folder\
|   |-- 128x128.png
|   |-- 16x16.png
|   |-- 24x24.png
|   |-- 256x256.png
|   |-- 32x32.png
|   |-- 48x48.png
|   L-- output.ico <- the icon will be generated
|-- second folder, identical to first one...
|-- and so on...
```

I tried this script without avail:

```
CD \final
SET argus=
FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") DO (
    SET argus=
    Echo We found %%~nxG
    cd %%~nxG
    for %%i in (*.png) do (
        SET argus=%argus% %%~nxi
    )
echo %argus%
    <path\to\icobundl.exe> -o %%~nxG.ico %argus%
    cd ..\
)
pause
```

But the *argus* variable, Which was supposed to get all png files in the folder (like *"file1.png file2.png ..."*) is always blank.
What i did wrong this time?

Answer (score 0):

Search SO for `delayed expansion`.

Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.

Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.

Two common ways to overcome this are 1) to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and use `!var!` in place of `%var%` to access the changed value of `var` or 2) to call a subroutine to perform further processing using the changed values.

Note therefore the use of `CALL ECHO %%var%%` which displays the changed value of `var`. `CALL ECHO %%errorlevel%%` displays, but sadly then RESETS errorlevel.

Answer (score 0):

If your subfolders have spaces in the name you've to always double quote them.
If there is only one level of folders you need only the `/D`option in the first for.
To ease testing I used variables with different values.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "IcoB=x:\path\to\icobundl.exe"
Set "Ext=.png"
Set "Base=%~dp0\final"

CD /D "%Base%"
FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO (
    SET "argus="
    Echo We found %%~nxG
    For %%I in ("%%G\*%Ext%") do (
        SET argus=!argus! %%~nxI
    )
    Echo !argus!
    "%IcoB%" -o "%%~nxG.ico" !argus!
)
pause
```